# LaTex: How to force constant linespacing

Tags: latex, xelatex

I am using `minipage` inside a `texblock` to put some lines of text at a specific place on my document.
My problem is, that the linespacing varies because of ascending/descending letters. I am using the font Papyrus Plain. https://www.download-free-fonts.com/details/112610/papyrus-plain

Example:

[image: Example]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\newcommand{\mytextbox}[1]{
\begin{textblock*}{0.1cm}(10.85cm,25.44cm) % {block width} (coords) 
\begin{minipage}[t][2cm][t]{\textwidth}
\vspace*{\fill}
   \fontsize{13}{12.3}\selectfont #1
   \vspace*{\fill}
\end{minipage}
\end{textblock*}}

\setmainfont{PapyrusPlain}
\begin{document}
\mytextbox{abcd efgh ijkl mnop}
\end{document}
```

I want the spacing like the first two lines of the example picture. I tried to fix this with surrounding it with

```
\begin{spacing}{1.0}
\mytextbox{abcd efgh ijkl mnop}
\end{spacing}
```

but this was ignored.

Comment: Please make a [mre] and not just code fragements

Comment: Sorry, I hope it is better now.

Comment: Thanks for editing! I think the problem is that the basekineskip is too small for your font size. If I increase it, say `\fontsize{13}{20}` I get equal line spacing. For normal fonts, the usual rule of thumb is that the baselineskip should be at least around 1.2 times the fontsize. For such a decorative font with pronounced ascenders and descenders, more is probably better

Comment: But the point is that I want the spacing smaller and not wider. And I don't mind if ascenders and descenders are touching each other. In fact I want them to touch each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `\baselineskip` is too small for your font size. If I increase it, say `\fontsize{13}{20}` I get equal line spacing. For normal fonts, the usual rule of thumb is that the `\baselineskip` should be at least around 1.2 times the font size. For such a decorative font with pronounced ascenders and descenders, more is probably better.

However if you really, really, really want to force smaller linespacing:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex


\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\newcommand{\mytextbox}[1]{
\begin{textblock*}{0.1cm}(10.85cm,25.44cm) % {block width} (coords) 
\begin{minipage}[t][2cm][t]{\textwidth}
\vspace*{\fill}
   \fontsize{13}{12.3}\selectfont 
   \setlength{\lineskiplimit}{-\maxdimen} 
   #1
   \vspace*{\fill}
\end{minipage}
\end{textblock*}}

\setmainfont{Papyrus}
\begin{document}
\mytextbox{abcd efgh abcg efgh}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, really, really, really want to force smaller linespacing :-) This works perfectly. Thank you very much.